# Suggest database table for picture path upload

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in which user can upload maximum 5 pictures but its upto the user that how much they upload pictures. If a user does not upload pics so what type of tricks I should apply.

So in this scenario what should i do ? or if i make five columns for every pic and if a user does not upload five pics so the empty columns will take bytes / space.
or i should make a dropdown option for storing path.

Kindly do not focus on code it is just to bypass rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 5 columns in table is not a desired and valid solution. Think a scenario when user can upload 10 pictures. Then? Will you alter table when your system goes live? No.

Create a new table called `user_file_manager`. Add records always in that table and have user reference column. So you can always know that which user has uploaded how many and which files.

Also just store the image names in the database table and define the image directory path in a configuration PHP file. And use that path in each and every files.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you want to know anything else.

Comment: i am storing pic in server and just storing path in database. my question is how i will upload path in db i mean if a user does not upload five pics so then what?

Comment: @MuhammadSubhan for each picture uploaded, you need to insert a fresh record in `user_file_manager` table and make `uid` column reference to `user` table. 
Consider simple table structure explained below: 
`fid` -- `uid` -- `filepath`

Comment: your are not getting to me, i am saying if a user does not upload five pics so then what? and how i will upload file path? i mean i should make five columns? and allow user to upload pics, and if he upload two pics, so the remains three i should leave it empty.

Comment: @MuhammadSubhan. If a user does not upload 5 pictures, then the `$_FILES` PHP array will be blank. In that case, you will not make any entries in `user_file_manager` table and you will not move any file in directory physically. Makes sense?

Comment: oh you are talking about coding side i am saying what should my DB design, what i have done yet it is i have made a image_id, image_path NOTE: image path is just one column, Now you suggest me that what should i do, need to make for columns more. Or what???

Comment: @MuhammadSubhan Please read my initial answer carefully. Yes you need to create a separate table. You need to insert individual records for all uploaded files. Say if user A uploads 3 files then make 3 entries in table. And create a column in that table to have user reference. Say User A's user ID is 55 and uploaded 3 images, then your file manager table must have 3 entries of user 55. Makes sense?

Comment: @MuhammadSubhan Yes now you are getting. 3 columns need to be there in your table. `fid` (Primary key, auto increment), `user_id` (Reference to user table), `file_path` (String which specifies image path). Always add records, never restrict logic to table columns. In this way you can add real dynamic behavior.

Comment: Thanks dude, i hope it will work, if it is does not work so i will contact you

Comment: @MuhammadSubhan. Any time. Please mark answer as correct if I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you normalize and create some more tables? Something like:

```
UserImages
---------
id int
user_id int (references Users.id)
image_id int (references Images.id)

Images
---------
id int
filepath string
```

Then in the server side code, restrict it to 5 images.

Comment: I don't think what he's talking about is a many-to-many relationship.. The `Images` table can just contain the `user_id` as a foreign key. No need for a junction table.